# Laravel handle Telegram webhooks

Tags: php, laravel, telegram

I'm fairly new to Laravel, and recently I tried to create a Telegram bot that can manage incoming messages and reply accordingly. Initially I plan to ask a user's name and use his name the next time the bot replies.

So how can I manage my bot's webhook which I already managed to set up.

```
Route::any('/setWebhook', function () {
    $response = Telegram::setWebhook([
        'url' => 'https://57f7-2806-104e-c-5c3b-3dc7-3284-7383-e130.ngrok.io/NdqvlJstHyIUhmNyTZhCYTnoYxdGzoPcLCzDiMiH/webhook'
    ]);
    dd($response);
});
```

How can I manage the bot's incoming updates? I'm currently using irazasyed sdk.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use a DB, which requires Model & migration
2. Telegram Bot API will send POST requests to your webhook
3. You should add `->middleware('api')`, because you'll receive data
4. Use `file_get_contents('php://input')` to get the update, Or use a library.

To me, I use [SimpleBotAPI library](https://github.com/Muaath5/SimpleBotAPI)

Simple code in SimpleBotAPI:

```php
// Handle updates here
class BotHandler extends UpdatesHandler
{
    public function MessageHandler($message) : bool
    {
        // Do whatever:
        $this->Bot->SendMessage(['chat_id' => $message->chat->id, 'text' => 'new Message!']);
        return true;
    }
}

Route::post('/bot_webhook', function () {
    $Bot = new TelegramBot(env('BOT_TOKEN'), new BotHandler());
    $Bot->OnWebhookUpdate();
})->middleware('api');
```